# What's the algorithm used in .NET to generate random numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, random

When I use `Random.Next()` what's the algorithm used by framework to return to me a "pseudorandom" number?

I read a little bit about [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Is this the technique used by .NET?

**EDIT:**

I look the [documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs) about `Random` class, but this is a famous technique? this algorithm has a name as the example (Linear congruential generator) ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with C#. It's part of .NET, and can be used from any managed programming language.

Comment: Take a look: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah, sorry, thanks by edit.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel this algorithm have a name? its a famous technique?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? *The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.*

Comment: Note that it looks like there is a bug in the implementation of the algorithm: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug

Answer (score 7):

It usually pays to check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) for this kind of thing:

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.

That brings me to this:

> http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Subtractive_generator

Also worth mentioning, from the same MSDN document:

> To generate a cryptographically secure random number suitable for creating a random password, for example, use a class derived from System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator such as System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

Specifically, the regular Random algorithm is weak because of this statement in the second link:

> Anyone who observes *i* consecutive numbers can predict the next numbers

Where *i* is not as large as you might think.

Comment: Implementing the code found through links in your answer, I am unable to produce the same sequence of numbers using the same seed with both the implemented code and System.Random. So while the same principals of the algorithm may be used by System..Random, the same algorithm it is not.